# $I$ proportional to $V$ or vice versa?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-current, voltage

I am confused whether Voltage depends on current or the vice versa. I always thought that the vice versa was correct. I tried to find the answers of some of my other conceptual doubts on the web but I was not able to understand the answers as people were saying things beyond school level. But the answers made me confused about the question about $V$ & $I$ mentioned above. Can you please tell which one is correct and why?

Also, please tell me why it is officially stated that $H = I^2RT$ not $VIT$.

Comment: Have you asked your teacher?

Comment: "Also, please tell me why it is officially stated that $H=I^2  Rt$, not ." I wouldn't say "officially". There are plenty of Physics textbooks where $Q=VIt$ is given as the primary formula. $Q=I^2Rt$ is a useful form for engineers calculating power dissipation in current-carrying wires.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ohm's law, like many (most?) physical laws, does not involve the idea of cause and effect.

I admit that I usually think of *V* as causing *I*, but an electronics engineer might put a resistor in a current-carrying circuit in order to produce a pd which can be applied across (say) a voltmeter. The current causes a voltage drop across the resistor!

I don't think there's any right or wrong here.

Comment: I believe that Ernst Mach (after whom *Mach numbers* are named) claimed that "There is no cause nor effect in nature. Nature simply *is*.

Answer (score 2):

> I am confused whether Voltage depends on current or the vice versa. I
> always thought that the vice versa was correct.

Both are true, but you have to know where the voltage and current are being measured to determine the dependence.

> Also, please tell me why it is officially stated that $H = I^2Rt$ not
> $VIt$.

Heat is only dissipated in resistance. For example, if the voltage $V$ and current $I$ are for an ideal capacitor or ideal inductor, there is no heating ($H=0$). Only the in phase components of voltage and current result in heating. So, for heating in an ac circuit, it would be

$$H=V_{rms}I_{rms}t \cos\theta$$

Where $\theta$ is the phase angle between the voltage and current and $rms$ is the root means square value of the current and voltage. For a purely resistive component, $\theta=90^0$, $\cos\theta=1$ and then $H=V_{rms}I_{rms}t$.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

They both depend on each other.If you have the IV diagram of a circuit element you can find the current for some voltage  across the element and you can find the voltage for some current through the element.

Comment: Don't forget various devices that have multiple operating regimes such that there are several possible currents at a given voltage (or vice versa), depending on how one gets there...

Comment: Yes that is correct (tunnel diodes,thyristors)